# Breaking an integer up into chunks, functionally

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Consider the problem of decomposing milliseconds into readable time units.  Imagine you had a function that did that

```
> breakupMillis(100000000)
Array [ 0, 40, 46, 3, 1 ]
```

meaning that 100 million milliseconds is 1 day, 3 hours, 46 minutes, and 40 seconds, exactly.

The function could be generalized by accepting an array of moduli, like this

```
> breakup(100000000, [1000, 60, 60, 24]) 
Array [ 0, 40, 46, 3, 1 ]
```

That function could be used (hypothetically) for other things:

```
> breakup(1000, [8, 8, 8]) 
Array [ 0, 5, 7, 1 ]
```

meaning that 1000 in decimal is 01750 in octal.

Here is the function I wrote to do this:

```
const breakup = (n, l) => l.map(p => 
    { const q = n % p; n = (n - q) / p; return q; }).concat(n);
```

This function is fine, it's even referentially transparent, but I have two, entirely esthetic, complaints.

- the `map`.  This feels like a job for `reduce`, though I don't see how.
- rewriting the variable `n`.  I don't like to use `var` at all; using a *secret* `var` makes it worse.

My question is only about the second.  How do I re-write the function so it uses no variable (that actually vary)?  If the `map` disappears, I'll take that as gravy.

Comment: I kinda have the feeling this belongs on codereview

Comment: In Haskell: `breakup n l = zipWith mod l . scanl div n l`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you can do it using a recursive procedure and a little helper `quotrem` – which given a numerator `n`, and a denominator `d`, returns `[<quotient>, <remainder>]`

```js
const quotrem = (n, d) => [n / d >> 0, n % d]

const breakup = (n, [x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined) {
    return [n]
  }
  else {
    let [q, r] = quotrem(n, x)
    return [r, ...breakup(q, xs)]
  }
}

console.log(breakup(1000, [8, 8, 8]))
// [ 0, 5, 7, 1 ]

console.log(breakup(100000000, [1000, 60, 60, 24]))
// [ 0, 40, 46, 3, 1 ]
```

If you're not particularly comfortable with the destructured array, you can add a few more helpers (`isEmpty`, `head`, and `tail`) to interact with the array in a more explicit way

```js
const isEmpty = xs => xs.length === 0
const head = xs => xs[0]
const tail = xs => xs.slice(1)
const quotrem = (n, d) => [n / d >> 0, n % d]

const breakup = (n, xs) => {
  if (isEmpty(xs)) {
    return [n]
  }
  else {
    let [q, r] = quotrem(n, head(xs))
    return [r, ...breakup(q, tail(xs))]
  }
}

console.log(breakup(1000, [8, 8, 8]))
// [ 0, 5, 7, 1 ]

console.log(breakup(100000000, [1000, 60, 60, 24]))
// [ 0, 40, 46, 3, 1 ]
```

Comment: I'd rather test for `arguments[1].length == 0`, not rely on the element never being `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the comment – I've added a secondary answer which handles the array a bit differently ^_^

Comment: I'm curious about the exact behavior of `>> 0`.  Is it identical to `Math.floor()`?

Comment: @Malvolio yea it's a quick way to drop the decimal portion of a Number

Answer (score 0):

> This feels like a job for `reduce`, though I don't see how.

Everything that iterates an array can be done with `reduce` :-)

We need to pass two things through (for the accumulator): the number that we still have the break, and the list of results. We can use ES6 destructuring and an array as a tuple:

```
function breakup(n, units) {
    const [n, res] = units.reduce(([n, res], u) => {
        const q = n % u;
        res.push((n-q) / u);
        return [q, res];
    }, [n, units]);
    return [n, ...res];
}
```

But that `push` is still ugly. Not only because it mutates (where we could have used `concat` as well), but what we really want is a function that abstracts this away. Unfortunately these don't exists in JS - we'd be looking for a [scan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:6) or [mapping accumulation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:7). We could write

```
function breakup(n, units) {
    const [rest, res] = units.mapAccum((n, u) => {
        const q = n % u;
        return [q, (n-q) / u];
    }, [n, units]);
    return [...res, rest];
}
function breakup(n, units) {
    const mods = units.scan((n, u) => Math.floor(n/u), units);
    return mods.map((q, i) => i<units.length ? q % units[i] : q);
}
```

I'll leave the (functional, efficient, readable, etc) implementation of those as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this code:

```js
const breakup = (n, l) => 
    l.reduce( ([n, ...res], p) => ([(n - n % p) / p, n % p, ...res]), [n])
     .reverse();

// Demo call
console.log(breakup(100000000, [1000, 60, 60, 24]));
```